# Final переменная для анонимного класса

Tags: java

Есть пример кода:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int a=5;
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Нужно использовать переменную `a` в анонимном классе, компилятор говорит объявить её как `final`.

Почему она должна быть `final`?

Comment: Переводить лень, но ответ по всей видимости можно найти [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class)

Comment: @Smirnov, да видимо недостаточно усердно искал решение, спасибо

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Это ограничение, которое ввели разработчики спецификации: при создании анонимного класса происходит захват объектов по значению, а не по ссылке. В анонимном классе создаются закрытые поля, в которые копируются значения переданных переменных. То есть по сути реализована эмуляция замыканий.

Добавление модификатора `final` как бы говорит программисту о том, что при использовании такого рода замыканий не будут наблюдаться побочные эффекты (представьте, что вы передали в созданный объект анонимного класса переменную, а затем изменили её "снаружи" - вы в праве ожидать, что это изменение отразится и внутри замыкания, но это не так в силу пресловутой эмуляции; однако изменение внутреннего состояния `mutable` объектов будет видно и там и там).

Для реализации полноценных замыканий необходимо расширять жизненный цикл захватываемых объектов (это касается объектов, расположенных в стеке, которые при выходе из области видимости, в которой они объявлены, уничтожаются).

Почему это не реализовано до сих пор? Для такого рода реализации необходимо внести серьезное изменение в саму архитектуру JVM. Такого рода изменения достаточно сложно внедрить по определенным причинам:

- потребуется много усилий для внесения изменений не только со стороны Oracle, но и со стороны сторонних разработчиков (дебаггеры, обфускаторы, IDE, компиляторы и т.д.).
- Внесение такого изменения может привести к утрате обратной совместимости, что отразится на множестве уже существующих приложений.
- Изменение может отразиться на других языках/платформах, завязанных на среде JVM.

В Java 8 ввели понятие `effectively final` - это переменные, которые не имеют модификатора `final`, но могут использоваться в анонимных классах и лямбда-выражениях. Переменная будет `effectively final`, если после её определения она не изменяется. Соответственно на Java 8 ваш код будет скомпилирован.

---

Дополнительные ссылки для более подробного ознакомления:

- [Accessing Members of an Enclosing Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html#accessing-members-of-an-enclosing-class),
- [Why are only final variables accessible in anonymous class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class)
- [Does Java 8 Support Closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204279/does-java-8-support-closures)

Answer (score 10):

Ваш код создаёт поток, поток запускается на выполнение, а вызвавшая поток функция (в данном случае `main`) может завершиться. При завершении функции все её локальные переменные, в том числе и `i` исчезнут, выделенная под них память возвратится системе. Следовательно, поток ***не должен*** иметь доступ к локальным переменным.

Но! Если у переменной Вы укажете квалификатор `final`, то Вы, фактически, говорите компилятору, что это не переменная, а ***константа***. Компилятор будет уверен, что после инициализации эта константа не изменится, поэтому со спокойной совестью вместо прямого обращения к переменной поставит внутри кода потока её копию.

Comment: +1, но тем не менее в C# этого ограничения нет, стековые переменные, попадая в замыкание, автоматически поднимаются в кучу. (А как с лямбдами?)