# Получение значения переменной из анонимного класса

Tags: java, android

Надо получить обработанную переменную `soapXml`. Как это сделать?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    public String soapXml = "";
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogg";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        et3.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
        {
            val3 = et3.getText().toString();
            receiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
            {
                @Override
                public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
                {

                    soapXml = intent.getStringExtra("xml");
                    tv.setText(soapXml); // здесь он выводит обработанную переменную
                }
            }
        });
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,soapXml) // здесь надо получить обработанную переменную soapXml, но в логе он выводит лишь "" и все. :(
}
```

Comment: Ваша проблема в том, что вы не понимаете как все это работает. То, что вы передали анонимный класс в метод, не означает что код в нем выполнится сразу же. Он выполнится тогда, когда его вызовет тот, кому вы его передали. А в какой момент это случится никому не известно, при определенных обстоятельствах этого вообще может не произойти. Следовательно вы никогда не получите обновленную переменную в том месте, где вы выводите ее в лог. Ищите другие пути решение.

Comment: Код некомпилируем, поправьте.

Answer (score 3):

В методе `setOnEditorActionListener` в качестве аргумента вы передаете экземпляр анонимного класса. В этом случае происходит захват переменных по значению. В вашем случае копируется по значению указатель на переменную `soapXml`, который затем изменяется. Но это изменение будет видно только внутри тела анонимного класса. Более [подробно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491452/final-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0/491511#491511), почему так происходит.

Как вариант, вы можете создать вложенный класс и его экземпляр передавать в качестве аргумента, откуда затем получать новое значение `soapXml`.

Второй вариант: создать вложенный класс, в котором обернуть объект типа `String` и экземпляр этого класса передавать в анонимный класс, тогда вы сможете извлечь новое значение строки извне замыкания. Пример:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private class SoapResponse {
       public String soapXml;
    }

    private SoapResponse soapResponse = new SoapResponse();
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogg";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        et3.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            val3 = et3.getText().toString();
            receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
                    soapResponse.soapXml = intent.getStringExtra("xml");
                    tv.setText(soapResponse.soapXml);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, soapResponse.soapXml);
}
```

Comment: можете поделиться примером кода как это сделать?

Comment: @Samur, добавил пример, код не тестировал, но думаю все будет нормально.

Comment: не работает :(  . В лог ничего не выводится

Comment: А логирование вы где вызываете?

Comment: в том месте где вы указали

Comment: Не совсем понял тогда. Вызов метода возможен либо в блоке инициализации, либо в другом методе. Я думал, вы просто указали, что потом вызываете этот метод. А так код не должен скомпилироваться

Comment: вызвал щас в методе onCreate, там тоже ничего не выводится в логе

Comment: Вы устанавливаете callback функцию на элемент, которая будет вызвана при наступлении события. Только после этого soapXml будет обновлена. До этого момента в логах не будет ничего

Comment: как тогда дождаться обновления SoapXml и вывести уже обновленный soapXml в лог?

Comment: Например, в методе onReceive, там вы обновляете переменную и там же можете выводить в лог.

Comment: ну в методе onReceive я изначально не хотел выводить, мне надо было в другом методе получить доступ к обноовленному soapXml