# Что означает final когда указано как модификатор к параметру?

Tags: java, android

Я уже не раз встречал, но только вот подумал... А что означает такая конструкция, когда допустим в методе один из параметров имеет модификатор доступа `final`...

Ведь в любом случае при повторном вызове метода ему можно передать новое значение...

Comment: При новом вызове можно, а вот внутри самого метода его изменить нельзя будет

Comment: Если сказать коротко, то он будет доступен "нижними уровнями", если у них нет ещё final'ов с таким же названием переменной.

Comment: Из комментариев можно понять, что на самом деле вас интересует ответ [на этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/491452/177345)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Если указан параметр `final` когда объявляется переменная, то его нельзя будет изменить.

   ```
   public void i1(final String i1) {
       i1 = ""; // ошибка компиляции
   }
   ```
2. Также параметр `final` даёт к себе доступ анонимным классам. Знаю такой пример на Android при запуске `Activity`:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(final Bundle i1) {
       super.onCreate(i1);
       setContentView(R.layout.layout_i1);
       new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
               .setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
               .setPositiveButton("ОК", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface i2, int i3) {
                       i1.clone(); // вот тут можем его получить Только потому, что у Bundle i1 указан параметр final
                       return;
                   }

               })
               .setNegativeButton("Выход", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface i1, int i2) {
                       i1.cancel();
                       finish();
                       return;
                   }

               })
               .create()
               .show();
   }
   ```

Ведь если заменить эту строку

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle i1) {
```

на это

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle i1) {
```

то вот здесь

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface i2, int i3) {
    i1.clone(); <<<--------- в этой строке
    return;
}
```

будет ошибка компиляции.

Comment: Указал пример на Android, так как под рукой нет обычной Java. Там таких примеров можно тоже сотню припомнить. По памяти могу ошибиться.

Comment: Именно этот пример с использование анонимных классов, то что было интересно... Только не совсем понял про нижние уровни... Почему они вызывают ошибку?

Comment: Про нижние уровни я просто так выразился. Это как бы подклассы. То есть, допустим, к примеру, класс в классе. Отредактирую вопрос, и, возможно, станет понятнее.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Это называется анонимные классы, а не нижние уровни. Необходимо финализировать передаваемые в анонимные классы параметры [по требованиям языка Java](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491511/177345).

Comment: Лучше всего выражаться в терминах языка программирования по которому вы пишите ответ (а не "я просто так выразился ..") иначе ваш ответ может не только не помочь, но и еще больше запутать

Comment: Как эти уровни по-другому назвать? Можете посмотреть мой ответ, я его отредактировал, возможно понятнее станет.

Comment: Можно повторить во второй раз - есть официалоьная терминология языка и там это называется *Анонимные классы*, а не нижние уровни или "как бы подклассы" и к "уровням" они как бы отношения вообще не имеют - это переопределение методов класса без создания ссылки на экземпляр класса.

Comment: Точно, вроде анонимные классы. Я тогда уберу всю эту пургу про уровни.

Answer (score 4):

Если у параметра в методе нет модификатора final, то переменную можно будет подменить другим объектом. Например:

```
void f(String x){
    x = "New";
    System.out.println(x); //"New"
}
```

Модификатор `final` у параметра исключает эту возможность

```
void f(final String x){
    x = "New"; // ошибка компиляции
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В прототипе метода, аргументы которые имеют модификатор final, нельзя переопределить в теле метода. 
А вообще, модификатор final, подсказывает компилятору, чтобы он сразу знал, что переменная, метод или класс - только для чтения.
Переменные final не инициализируются по умолчанию, им необходимо явно присвоить значение при объявлении или в конструкторе, иначе – ошибка компиляции.

Answer (score 0):

Это нужно для уверенности, что во время выполнения метода нигде не было переопределенно значение аргумента , например.

```
  public static String method(final String city) {
        city = "Moscow"; //ошибка
        return city;
    }
```

Comment: Вообще-то не только.

Comment: @L'Esperanza интересно узнать и для чего же еще?

Comment: Сейчас напишу ответ.

Comment: строго говоря это сработает для String-a, а вот для изменяемого объекта нет - ссылку, действительно изменить нельзя, а вот значение по ссылке легко

Comment: хм, естественно. по моему это очевидно

Comment: @Artem Konovalov есть правило, согласно которому то что приходит в метод должно остаться неизменным после его исполнения

Comment: я не слышал про такое правило, где вы его прочитали? java это не функциональный язык и тут разрешаются не pure функции.

Comment: это влияние функционального подхода :)

Answer (score 0):

На пример что бы можно было сделать так:

```
 void method(final int i) {
      mMember.setListener(new Listener() {
         public void call() {
            System.out.println(i);
         }
      });
 }
```

Comment: Не всегда верно, в java 8 появилось такое понятие как effective final. Компилятор может сам догадаться в каких случаях переменная неизменяется и ему не нужно подсказывать словом final.

Comment: в вопросе есть тег android

Comment: @Artem Konovalov, В Java 8 - да. А с Java 7 как? android отличается от Java только тем, что там классы есть другие.

Comment: в java 8 код без final скомпилируется, ниже нет